# In makefiles what do CC and LD stand for?

Tags: makefile

In makefiles what do ***CC*** (compiler) and ***LD*** (linker) stand for?

C in CC is probably compiler, what is the other C?
And L in LD is probably linker, what does the D stand for?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Names of these variables originate from names of the corresponding tools. Usually the meaning of these abbreviations is the following:

- `CC` stands for "**C** **c**ompiler" (in GCC abbreviation it is also treated as "**c**ompiler **c**ollection").
- `LD` is a linker (comes from "**l**ink e**d**itor" or from "**l**oa**d**er").

These are also commonly used in makefiles (see [Implicit variables chapter](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Variables) of GNU Make manual):

- `CPP` stands for "**C** **p**re**p**rocessor"
- `CXX` is a **C++** compiler
- `AS` is an **as**sembly language compiler
- `AR` is an **ar**chive-maintaining program

Answer (score 2):

CC is "C Compiler". LD is "Link Editor". LE was already used to mean "less or equal" in a shell, likely sh. So, per convention, the conflicting character was moved one character forward in the word being abbreviated. Hence LD and DYLD.

Comment: I would love a source for this! I'm tempted to believe it

Answer (score 1):

`$(CC)` is the C compiler (or compiler collection), `$(LD)` is the linker, as you suspected. The D stands for "Dynamic", I believe.

Comment: compiler collection? Can there be two compilers specified inside?

Comment: No, I ment can I put g95 and ifort inside and then compile the file twice (checking for errors on two compilers) without repeating the  whole other part of the script ... never mind. I got my answer, anyhow.